# The difference between the model and query builder method when using get and first on laravel?

Tags: laravel, collections, model, laravel-query-builder

if I just want to get the only one column name

--use model--------

```
$model_use_get  =Model::select('name')->where('id','=',10)->get();

$want=$model_use_get[0]['name'];

$model_use_first=Model::select('name')->where('id','=',10)->first();

$want=$model_use_first['name'];
```

---use query builder-----

```
$query_use_get  =DB::table('a1)->select('name')->where('id','=',10)->get();

$want=$query_use_get[0]->name;

$query_use_first=DB::table('a1)->select('name')->where('id','=',10)->first();

$want=$query_use_first->name;
```

what's the difference? Does not both model or query method make a collection? or object?(array?) I confused!!!
Is there any direct method to just get the one select ,not need to process again?
like below  (I confirm the result is only one because I use where id=xxx)

```
$want=model::select('name)->.... 
$want=DB::table('a1')->select('name').....
```

Comment: thanks typing error ,fix already.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is pretty simple:

- `first()` gets single record from database
- `get()` gets collection of items (similar to array)

So for `first()` you can get model property using `$model->property` but for `get` you have multiple items, so you can get properties using loop:

```
foreach ($models as $model) {
   $model->property;
}
```

When you run `get()` and later `first` like this you run 2 queries, but you can call `first` also on items you already got from database:

```
$models = Model::select('name')->where('id','=',10)->get();

foreach ($models as $model) {
   echo $model->name;
}

$firstModel = $models->first();

$want = $firstModel->name;
```

Comment: But I want to get the result which I confirm is only one result. So can I use $models=Model::.... ->get()->first()  and $models->name?  omiting the foreach ?

Comment: $A=A->get() ,  $B=$A->first()  two step  is different from the one step $B=A->get()->first()  or $B=A->first() ?

Comment: @robspin If you are sure, there is only 1 record, you should use `A->first()`. It will just take single record from database and you can access model directly (without any loop)

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, the combination of `Model`, `DB::table()`, `->get()` and `->first()` all return different things.

1st instance, `Model` and `->get()`:

```
$collection = Model::get(); 
// Returns a `Collection` of `Model` records, constrained to your additional query logic.
```

2nd, `Model` and `->first()`:

```
$model = Model::first(); 
// Returns a single `Model`, or `null`, based on your query logic.
```

3rd, `DB::table()` and `->get()`:

```
$collection = DB::table("table")->get(); 
// Returns a `Collection` of `stdClass` objects, based on your query logic.
```

4th, `DB::table()` and `->first()`:

```
$record = DB::table("table")->first(); 
// Returns a single `stdClass`, or `null`, based on your query logic.
```

Hopefully that clears everything up. There are additional closures, such as `find()`, `findOrFail()`, `paginate()`, etc, that all return similar things, so play with those and see what works best for your needs.

Comment: So query is single stdClass , use $result->name; query is a collection, use $result[0]['name'] to get the first item?  Paginate must be a collection,so use $paginate[0]['name']?  But when controller send to view use with(result,$result), it become a stdClass on blade,use $result->name?

Comment: Not quite. When it's a `Model` or `stdClass`, use `$model->{property}`, like name, to access the name. When it's a `Collection`, use a loop to access each `Model` or `stdClass`, or `$collection->first()->{property}`, or `$collection[index]->{property}`. Passing it to a view doesn't change the type.